# Unable to return stored procedure results to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, vba

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that I am calling from Excel, passing through some dynamic parameters each time.

I know the stored procedure works with the parameters in SQL Server (have tested this extensively), however when I call the procedure through Excel I get no results returned.

My connection is set up in Data==>Connections and is working - it pulls back the column names straightaway. It runs from a CommandButton, vba is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim HOT As String, RM As String, Season As String, SSD As Date, SED As Date

HOT = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
RM = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Value
Season = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Value

If Season = "S16" Then
    SSD = "01/05/2016"
    SED = "31/10/2016"
ElseIf Season = "W16" Then
    SSD = "01/11/2016"
    SED = "30/04/2016"
ElseIf Season = "S17" Then
    SSD = "01/05/2017"
    SED = "31/10/2017"
Else
End If

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("TRRC").OLEDBConnection
    .CommandText = "EXEC RatesCalculation '" & Season & "','" & HOT & "','" & RM & "'"
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("TRRC").Refresh
End With
End Sub
```

The season information isn't relevant, as in everything in the IF statement, I have a statement within my stored procedure to define the dates with the season.

I also have `SET NOCOUNT ON` in the stored procedure.

Below is my stored procedure:

```
    @Season Char(3), @RM Char(6), @HOT Char(6)

AS

BEGIN


    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @SSD as Datetime
    DECLARE @SED as Datetime

    IF @Season = 'S16'
        SET @SSD = '01/05/2016'
    IF @Season = 'S16'
        SET @SED = '31/10/2016'
    IF @Season = 'W16'
        SET @SSD = '01/11/2016'
    IF @Season = 'W16'
        SET @SED = '30/04/2017'

--gathering room data (rates, dates) (#tblroomrates)
SELECT DISTINCT holhot.hot, prxcontract.ssnver, prxcontract.conid, atchotroom.atcCode, prxconrate.room, prxconrate.dateid, prxcondate.dateStart, prxcondate.dateEnd, prxconrate.type, prxconrate.rate1, prxconrate.rate2
INTO            #tblroomrates
FROM            atchotroom INNER JOIN
                         prxconroom ON atchotroom.room = prxconroom.atchotroom INNER JOIN
                         prxconrate INNER JOIN
                         prxcondate ON prxconrate.ssnver = prxcondate.ssnver AND prxconrate.conId = prxcondate.conId 
                         AND prxconrate.dateId = prxcondate.dateId ON 
                         prxconroom.ssnver = prxconrate.ssnver AND prxconroom.conId = prxconrate.conId 
                         AND prxconroom.room = prxconrate.room INNER JOIN
                         holhot INNER JOIN
                         name ON holhot.hot = name.tosCode INNER JOIN
                         prxcon ON name.code = prxcon.hot INNER JOIN
                         prxcontract ON prxcon.ssnver = prxcontract.ssnver 
                         AND prxcon.conId = prxcontract.conId ON prxconroom.ssnver = prxcontract.ssnver AND 
                         prxconroom.conId = prxcontract.conId AND atchotroom.code = prxcon.hot
WHERE        (holhot.holcode = @HOT) AND (prxcon.ssnver = '') AND 
                         (prxcontract.constart<=@SED) AND (prxcontract.conend>=@SSD)
                         order by datestart asc;

--updating any blank dates to season dates to represent an all season rate(only applies to type 3 and 4)
UPDATE #tblroomrates
SET #tblroomrates.datestart = prxcontract.constart,
    #tblroomrates.dateend = prxcontract.conend
FROM
    #tblroomrates INNER JOIN prxcontract ON #tblroomrates.ssnver = prxcontract.ssnver AND #tblroomrates.conid = prxcontract.conid
WHERE
    #tblroomrates.datestart is null AND #tblroomrates.dateend is null

--selects all type 3 and 4 rates for all season dates (#tblrates_alldates)
SELECT DISTINCT #tblroomrates.ssnver, #tblroomrates.conid, atcCode, room, dateid, dateStart, dateEnd, [type], rate1, rate2
INTO #tblrates_alldates
FROM #tblroomrates INNER JOIN prxcontract ON #tblroomrates.ssnver = prxcontract.ssnver AND #tblroomrates.conid = prxcontract.conid
WHERE #tblroomrates.dateStart = prxcontract.constart AND #tblroomrates.dateEnd = prxcontract.conend
AND #tblroomrates.[type] IN ('3','4')

--rate update
UPDATE #tblroomrates
SET 
    #tblroomrates.rate1 = #tblrates_alldates.rate1,
    #tblroomrates.rate2 = #tblrates_alldates.rate2
FROM
    #tblroomrates INNER JOIN #tblrates_alldates ON #tblroomrates.ssnver = #tblrates_alldates.ssnver AND #tblroomrates.conid = #tblrates_alldates.conid AND #tblroomrates.room = #tblrates_alldates.room
    INNER JOIN prxcontract ON #tblroomrates.ssnver = prxcontract.ssnver AND #tblroomrates.conid = prxcontract.conid
WHERE
    #tblroomrates.dateStart = prxcontract.constart AND #tblroomrates.dateEnd = prxcontract.conend AND #tblroomrates.dateid >'0'

--gathers rates where type is 1 (#tblrates_baserates)
SELECT DISTINCT * 
INTO #tblrates_baserates
FROM #tblroomrates
WHERE [type] = '1'

--update rate 2
UPDATE #tblroomrates
SET 
    #tblroomrates.rate1 = #tblrates_baserates.rate1
FROM 
    #tblroomrates INNER JOIN #tblrates_baserates ON #tblroomrates.ssnver = #tblrates_baserates.ssnver AND #tblroomrates.conid = #tblrates_baserates.conid 
    AND #tblroomrates.dateid = #tblrates_baserates.dateid
WHERE
    #tblroomrates.[type] = '2'

--Calculate the final rate here
SELECT #tblroomrates.hot AS [Accom Code], #tblroomrates.atcCode AS [Room], #tblroomrates.dateStart AS [Rate Start], #tblroomrates.dateEnd AS [Rate End], 
        CASE 
            WHEN #tblroomrates.rate2 <> 0 AND #tblroomrates.[type] = 3 THEN #tblrates_baserates.rate1 + #tblroomrates.rate2
            WHEN #tblroomrates.rate2 <> 0 AND #tblroomrates.[type] = 4 THEN #tblrates_baserates.rate1 - #tblroomrates.rate2 
            WHEN #tblroomrates.rate2 <> 0 AND #tblroomrates.[type] IN (0,1,2) THEN #tblroomrates.rate1
            ELSE 
                CASE
                    WHEN #tblroomrates.rate1 <> 0 AND #tblroomrates.[type] = 3 THEN #tblrates_baserates.rate1 + (#tblrates_baserates.rate1 * (#tblroomrates.rate1/100))
                    WHEN #tblroomrates.rate1 <> 0 AND #tblroomrates.[type] = 4 THEN #tblrates_baserates.rate1 - (#tblrates_baserates.rate1 * (#tblroomrates.rate1/100))
                    ELSE 
                        CASE
                            WHEN #tblroomrates.rate2 = 0 AND #tblroomrates.rate1 = 0 THEN #tblrates_baserates.rate1
                            ELSE #tblroomrates.rate1
                        END
                END
        END AS Calculated_Rates
FROM #tblroomrates LEFT JOIN #tblrates_baserates ON #tblroomrates.ssnver = #tblrates_baserates.ssnver AND 
    #tblroomrates.conid = #tblrates_baserates.conid AND #tblroomrates.dateid = #tblrates_baserates.dateid
WHERE #tblroomrates.dateid > 0
AND #TBLROOMRATES.ATCCODE = @RM
```

Quite a hefty chunk but required to gather all the data needed for the final calculation

Comment: You should set `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in the `.CommandText` like so: `.CommandText = "set nocount on; EXEC RatesCalculation '" & Season & "','" & HOT & "','" & RM & "'"`

Comment: @Ralph, makes no difference, still get no results returned

Comment: Did you verify the resulting `Debug.Print "EXEC RatesCalculation '" & Season & "','" & HOT & "','" & RM & "'"` to see if the T-SQL command is correct and try to run this resulting line in SSMS? If this still verifies then check the credentials used in SSMS as compared to Excel. If you still didn't find out the problem then you need to add the T-SQL code to your above post as well.

Comment: Looking at your SP it seems that it normally returns multiple results. Yet, Excel is not able to retrieve more than one result-set. `Set nocount on;` ensures that only the last return will be accepted by Excel. In your case that would be `--Calculate the final rate here`. So, if this `select` turns out to be empty then Excel will not show anything. You might want to (in a first step) start with a simple SP just to verify the various outcomes in Excel.

Comment: @Ralph, 'debug.print' shows me the expected values to be passed to the stored procedure

Comment: @Ralph, make a second SP to query and return the last results from the first SP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what was advised above, I split my stored procedure down into 2 separate procedures - 1 to gather all the relevant data, and the second to do my final calculations. I think it was as Ralph suggested, with Excel not knowing which result set to pull back and display. So problem solved. Result is however showing the wrong figures, but that's a maths issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user that the Excel sheet is authenticating with has permission to EXECUTE on the database. SELECT is not enough. You don't need to worry about permission to perform any of the operations that happen inside the SP, since SP's operate with the same permissions as the object owner (unlike Views etc).

Comment: The stored procedure is executed with the permissions of an admin, as in the same permissions I use on the server daily

Comment: Do you have "Refresh this connection on Refresh All" checked in the connection properties?